# Format Excel column as text

Tags: c#, .net, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# extract formatted text from Excel through OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282410/c-sharp-extract-formatted-text-from-excel-through-oledb)

Can i somehow format an excel column and it's data as text, before fetching the data from it ?
I'm using C# and .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix the number by ' for example '100 will be shown as text.

Comment: I can't touch the content of the excel file. It's generated by software, and i have to import it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

You can can try `myCell.Style.NumberFormat = "@"`

Here is an example online that should help give you an idea on how to use it:

- [Example](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1218.htm)

### Option 2

Alternatively you could try grabing `myCell.Text` instead of `myCell.Value`. Value is what is actually stored in the cell, whereas Text is what is displayed.

Comment: Thank you! Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @maephisot: I updated the example to include sample code I found via Google.

Comment: I'm using OleDB to connent to the excel file, and fill a datatable, so i can't acces value or text. This would've been great though...

Comment: Your Example 2 link is broken.

Comment: @Sheridan: Thanks, I removed it.