# C# extract formatted text from Excel through OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, connection-string, oledb

I am reading data from a large `excel` file which has got formatted texts. I extract the data to `DataTable` object through `oleDBConnection` & `GetOleDbSchemaTable`. But the extracted data doesn't include any formatted information.

My requirement is, I need to extract only non-Strikethrough texts.

I don't have any issues while reading and everything is perfectly fine. But my extraction should be based on text format in `excel` which I am unable to find the solution.

Anything to be added in the `connectionString` which is as follows:

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Mode=Read;ReadOnly=True;\"";
```

Constraints:

1. Using OleDBConnection - No Interop
2. Reading to DataTable Object

Comment: Oledb will only read cell values, not the formatted version of those values.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot do this with just the ACE driver. That being said, if the constraints are ever lifted, this is the tool to use: 
http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for information !The contraint is because the data in datatable will be later updated to MS SQL Server DB. The datatable data is used by dataGrid for display purposes and also for writing to text files.

Comment: I understand, but you can achieve the same goal with the ClosedXML API. it's not as terse as just ripping the data using OLEDB, but it WILL get the job done in the fashion you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch your approach to use open XML.  It's .NET, not COM

Info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840817

Download SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Open Xml" to get to format information if you do not want to use Interop. There is no other choice. There is Biff which I mention only for correctness, but your connection string clearly indicates XML, so Biff is out.

Once you open through "Open Xml" then you can "simulate" reading the range/table/cells like a `DataTable`.

With your constraints, Only #1 will give you formatting information.